# Glassfish in Eclipse intermittently deploys partially

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, vaadin, helios

Whenever I perform Run on Server in eclipse helios on my dynamic web maven project with no-interface EJBs, Glassfish intermittently deploys it partially. A successful deployment typically logs with these:

```
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504
SEVERE: line 1:53 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'
SEVERE: line 1:53 no viable alternative at character ' '
SEVERE: line 1:81 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'
INFO: file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/suffuse-management-console/WEB-INF/classes/_suffuse-management-console13331114 login successful
WARNING: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@181f00a].
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@181f00a] from index [0] 
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@189b558] from index [1] 

INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB UniversalEAO : [java:global/suffuse-management-console/UniversalEAO, java:global/suffuse-management-console/UniversalEAO!neverfall.suffuse.management.services.UniversalEAO]
INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB UserAuthenticationService : [java:global/suffuse-management-console/UserAuthenticationService, java:global/suffuse-management-console/UserAuthenticationService!neverfall.suffuse.management.services.UserAuthenticationService]
INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB ProjectEntityProvider : [java:global/suffuse-management-console/ProjectEntityProvider!neverfall.suffuse.management.services.ProjectEntityProvider, java:global/suffuse-management-console/ProjectEntityProvider]
INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB ProjectManagementService : [java:global/suffuse-management-console/ProjectManagementService!neverfall.suffuse.management.services.ProjectManagementService, java:global/suffuse-management-console/ProjectManagementService]

INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [suffuse-management-console] at [/suffuse-management-console]
INFO: suffuse-management-console was successfully deployed in 8,781 milliseconds.
```

However, it occasionally partially deploys with only this

```
INFO: file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/suffuse-management-console/WEB-INF/classes/_suffuse-management-console20748433 logout successful

INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [suffuse-management-console] at [/suffuse-management-console]
INFO: suffuse-management-console was successfully deployed in 5,461 milliseconds.
```

I get 404 errors when accessing my servlets. To fully deploy it, I must execute Project -> Clean then execute Run on Server again without removing the resource and it does it fine. Anyone know of the reason behind this and a permanent remedy?